# Adding rare languages to Apache Solr

Tags: solr, tokenize, multilingual, solr4, solr6

We would like to add support for Filipino, Lao, Malaysian and Vietnamese to our Solr Index (Solr v4 and Solr v6) and would be delighted to get hints on what Tokenizer to use.

For Lao I found that the ICU-Tokenizer seems to support it, but I was not able to find any configuration examples with rules for Lao: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/language-analysis.html#LanguageAnalysis-Hebrew_Lao_Myanmar_Khmer

Any help would be more than welcome! Thanks!!